# Spark - filter vs List added

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

```
val rtnRdd = originRdd.filter( ~~~ ) // 1

// 2
var eventList: List[myType] = Nil
originRdd.foreach{
    if( some condition)
        eventList :+= myType( ~~ )
}
// eventList convert to RDD
```

Which way is proper and fast way in spark? if '1' is proper way, why shouldn't I use '2' code style?

Comment: both would be same I guess as both are linear. style 2 uses var so you have to cautious while using it in distributed system.

Comment: Is there any other side effect when i use style '2' in distributed system?

Comment: use of var might get you inconsistent results as they are mutables and other objects or functions can modify them. Thats the only side effect i know of when using var.

Answer (score 1):

2nd style is not favored because functional programming leans towards more using expression over statements. In second statements, we are using statements. Statements causes side effects. Besides that, you are doing assignment programming which also causes side effects. It becomes hard to parallelize it.  For more info [refer](http://blog.agiledeveloper.com/2015/08/functional-programming-favors.html)